# ¿Como mostrar mensaje ouput de SQL en un messageBox en c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

```
**Este es mi procedimiento Almacenado**

@Nombre varchar(150),
@codigo int,
@Resultado int output,
@Mensaje varchar(500) output
)as
begin
 set @Resultado = 0
 if not exists (select * from pruebas where codigo = @codigo)
 begin
 insert into pruebas (Nombre,codigo,fecha) `values(@Nombre,@codigo,GETDATE())
 set @Resultado = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
 end
 else
 set @Mensaje ='Ya existe un nombre con el mismo codigo'
 end`
```

A la hora de mostrar un mensaje con `MessageBox.Show`, este me sale vacío. Para mostrarlo, hago lo siguiente:

```
string mensaje = string.Empty;         
try
  {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("prueba", Conexion);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Codigo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox2.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Resultado", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mensaje", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    Conexion.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     mensaje = cmd.Parameters["@Mensaje"].Value.ToString();
    Conexion.Close();
  }catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(mensaje);
  }
```

El inconveniente está en que no se muestra el mensaje pese a estar programado en `SQL` a traves de `OUTPUT`

Comment: Que mensaje esperas que salga y donde??? todo ese codigo esta en la UI?

Comment: Si te sale vacío es porque está saliendo por el `catch` por lo que deberías hacer esto:  `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);` de esta manera, sabrás cuál es el problema. Saludos!

Comment: Eric, más allá del procedimiento de almacenado, lo que necesitamos saber es que está saliendo por el `CATCH` Has caso a lo recomendado por Jesús y a lo que te digo, Corrige `MessageBox.Show` del `CATCH`

Comment: Ya lo resolví, gracias por la ayuda. mi problema esta en el catch.

Answer (score 1):

La caja de mensaje (`MessageBox`) sólo sale cuando falla la ejecución del procedimiento almacenado, ya que está dentro del `catch`, seguramente el error ocurre en `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` y por tanto no se ejecuta la línea que establece el valor de la variable mensaje, sino que salta directamente al `catch`, por eso el la caja muestra un mensaje vacío, tal y como lo has inicializado al principio. Quizá sería mejor que la caja de mensaje mostrara el mensaje de error, en vez del valor del parámetro de salida que no está disponible cuando la llamada al procedimiento falla.

Comment: Lo que estoy haciendo es un insert mediante Procedimiento Almacenado y a la ves le estoy diciendo que cuando agreguen un nuevo registro y este ya existe, mande el mensaje de que el dato ya esta registrado.

Comment: Disculpa, pero eso que dices no aclara nada. Veamos qué trae la excepción para orientarte mejor. Y sin ver el código del procedimiento almacenado, estamos a ciegas. Se te olvida incluir toda la información relevante, así es muy difícil porder ayudarte

Comment: Lo único que te podemos decir y deberías entender es que sólo intentas mostrar el mensaje cuando el procedimiento falla y en este caso no están disponibles los parámetros de salida.

Comment: Así es, eso es lo que quiero, mostrar el mensaje de error cuando el procedimiento falla, pero no eh podido hacerlo, soy principiante en programación.

Comment: MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

Comment: Y yo lo que quiero es que muestres el código del procedimiento almacenado, el mensaje de error y la pila de llamadas. A ver si aprendemos a hacer preguntas en SO. Porque si no, las respuestas no te van a solucionar el problema, o simplemente nadie te va a responder

Comment: Ya agregue mi procedimiento almacenado en mi publicación